# Need a formula that finds all 16 digit numbers in a cell

Tags: excel, function

I have a spreadsheet in a particular cell which is a URL, along with a 16 digit number, and is always in the right, i need an excel function that looks for this 16 digit number within that cell and verifies it exists on this cells

this is an example of a data, https://www.blahblah.com/en/our-services/distribution/uk-distribution/parcel-tracking/?trackingNo=5655886586205093.

im needed of a function that looks in a data likes this and finds every 16 digit number within this data.

Any idea?

Comment: a sample of your data might be helpful

Comment: And some idea of the structure of the data in that particular cell.

Comment: what about RIGHT() function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your data looks and what you are after, `RIGHT` will help you get the 16 digit number if your address looks like this:

```
somesortofaddress.com/1872965370982716

=RIGHT(A1, FIND("/", A1)-1)
```

You can tie this in with a `LEN` function to check how long that string is:

```
=LEN(RIGHT(A1, FIND("/", A1)-1))    'will return 16'
```

Or if you just want to know if there is a 16 digit number in there throw it all inside an `IF`

```
=IF(LEN(RIGHT(A1, FIND("/", A1)-1))=16, "Exists", "Doesn't Exist")
```

This should at least be a starting point, hard to answer exactly without sample data. Good luck.

EDIT*

With your example provided just use `=RIGHT(A1, 16)` will return the first 16 characters from a web address, alternatively use this `=RIGHT(A1, FIND("=", A1)-1)` which will return everything after the `=`.